# Error creating new Azure Bot Service instance?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to create a bot service on Azure following the quickstart on docs but clicking on "NEW" button nothing happens. The page seens to loading indefinitely. In fact, none is working in the dashboard. When click on config button a lot of warnings and many of messages "Error on loading this block" are showed.

Comment: Are you sure you have permission to create AD Apps? Similar to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883255/ajax-extended-call-failed-in-azure/47893415#47893415

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest you add one of the tags with 'azure' to your question; it is very unspecific as of now. Also check  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask an awesome question! It drastically reduces work for people wanting to help you and improves your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Think I have permissions. This is occuring since yesterday in my free trial account.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the error(s)?

Comment: Also, is your subscription still active? You could have these issues if your free trial has ran up

Comment: Yes, the subscription is active!